# How to audit in a for-loop (Hibernate envers)?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am using hibernate envers for auditing. 
It works fine but today I realized that it doesnt if I create entities in a for-loop.
After set log true for sql queries I figured out, that the rev-tables are not updated after each iteration. Somehow hibernate collects all changes and fires the audit command in the end of a request? How can I let hibernate to do auditing after each iteration in my for-loop?

What I already tried:

```
for (...) {

 Obj a = new Obj();
 objRepository.save(a);

 entityManager.flush();
 entityManager.clear();
}
```

Comment: I think that hibernate fires audit command at transaction commits.

Answer (score 0):

As [@gtosto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634594/gtosto) points out, Hibernate Envers operates on a transaction boundary basis and therefore audit records won't be flushed and persisted until commit.

One way to synchronize this would be to manually control the transaction boundary yourself as a part of the for-loop so you basically persist small buckets of the list and commit.

The downside here is that can be performance intensive, particularly if the list of objects you're trying to persist is quite large.

The jira issue [HHH-9622](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9622?) outlines a request to make the `AuditProcess` flushable; however, there are consequences to introducing such behavior that need to be considered.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the problem was that I added the @Transactional annotation to the respective class. Remove it and hibernate will fire the audit commands as soon as you call `objRepository.save(a)`. No need for entity manager.

Comment: That ultimately depends on expectations.  With an outer `@Transactional` in place, that means its all or nothing type of commit.  If one entity fails to be persisted, they all fail and are rolled back.  Removing this outer `@Transactional` means that any entities persisted up to a failure will remain persisted.  It also means that you're not doing bulk operations with your for-loop and you may notice a drop in performance.  It's important to understand transaction management here and make sure you're doing what is logical right for your use case.